# How to do a speed meter UI like curved slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, slider

[image: The image shows that, a UI to choose the weight]
Here I am working with flutter, and here, how to achieve this weight choosing curve, also I want to concurrently show the weight.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fd59d240beb8dd9d780f978e5c76b3c#file-sized_content_scrollable-dart-L250